# INNER JOIN always returns 1 row (even if its empty)?

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have a method that returns data from a tournament system I am creating. I have an issue where the INNER JOIN query always returns one row, not matter if the WHERE clause is true or not.

In the database there are two tournaments, both with a T.game = '1' - yet if I check the query for T.game = '2', it still returns a row according to `mysql_num_rows()`, and when I `print_r()` the resulting array, it is empty except for the COUNT() row, yet shouldn't the WHERE clause not find any rows and portray this accordingly to the `mysql_num_rows()` ?

I guess my main question is how do i stop the COUNT(P.id) from always displaying even when there are no matched rows in the tournaments table

```
public function fetchTournaments($gameID){
        if($gameID == "" || $this->hasChar($gameID) || $this->hasSymb($gameID)){
            $this->_errorMsg = "Invalid Game ID.";
            return false;
        }else{
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT
                                    T.id,
                                    T.name,
                                    T.description,
                                    T.checkin,
                                    DATE_FORMAT(T.date,'%b %d, %Y @ %h:%i %p') AS date,
                                    COUNT(P.id) AS playernum
                                  FROM tournaments T
                                  INNER JOIN players P
                                  ON T.id = P.tourney_id
                                  WHERE T.game='{$gameID}'") or die(mysql_error());
            $result = mysql_num_rows($query);
            if($result > 0){
                echo $result;
                $output = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                return $output;
            }else{
                $this->_errorMsg = "There are no tournaments for this game.";
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Also please don't mention that I shouldn't use mysql_* functions, I have yet to change to objects to use prepared statements.

Comment: Can you add "HAVING COUNT(P.id) > 0" in there somewhere?

Comment: Thank you that works, realized I had another problem though - the COUNT(P.id) is always return the full table instead of just the ones where I set using the INNER JOIN.. thoughts ?

Comment: That's where you use "GROUP BY T.id, T.name, T.description, T.checkin, T.date"  That way you're applying the aggregate function (count) to the groupings created.  If you don't specify groupings, you get the whole table.  (In some flavors of SQL, not having the explicit groupings would have caused an error in your case.)

Comment: The problem lies in the SQL query, not in the PHP code. Can you edit your question to provide a sample schema and data in the form of [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) and [`INSERT ... VALUES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statements? Otherwise, I will make assumptions when answering your question by defining my own data.

Comment: Thank you pilotcam, you should have posted an answer then i'd have given you the green check ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, `COUNT` (like other aggregate functions) will always return a result. You may be able to get around this by using `GROUP BY`, which will return the results of the aggregate for each row. You might want to play with the columns you list in the `GROUP BY`, but maybe something like:

```php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT
                    T.id,
                    T.name,
                    T.description,
                    T.checkin,
                    DATE_FORMAT(T.date,'%b %d, %Y @ %h:%i %p') AS date,
                    COUNT(P.id) AS playernum
                  FROM tournaments T
                  INNER JOIN players P
                  ON T.id = P.tourney_id
                  WHERE T.game='{$gameID}'
                  GROUP BY T.id,T.name,T.description,T.checkin,date") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: The query was more of a starting point - you would probably need to list all the columns in the `GROUP BY` line as I've edited my answer to show.

Comment: yes i realized this thanks to pilotcam, hence my deleted comment LOL - thanks by the way

Comment: haha, now I look like I'm talking to myself. good luck with it!